# Why does my MacBook Air 2013 wake from sleep every minute on Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, macos

I'm having issues with my MacBook Air 2013 waking from sleep into Dark Wake every minute since I upgraded to Mavericks. Whenever it's been to sleep and goes into standby it keeps waking up. This is what `pmset -g log` looks like:

```
2013-10-25 06:52:41 CEST DarkWake               DarkWake [CDN]  : Using BATT (Charge:60%)                                   45 secs   
2013-10-25 06:53:26 CEST Assertions             PID 18(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0xe00001348 [System: No Assertions]              
2013-10-25 06:53:26 CEST Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:60%)                                  16 secs   
2013-10-25 06:53:28 CEST SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from com.apple.apsd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                    1996 ms       
2013-10-25 06:53:28 CEST WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                                   
2013-10-25 06:53:42 CEST Assertions             PID 18(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0xe0000135c [System: No Assertions]           
2013-10-25 06:53:42 CEST DarkWake               DarkWake [CDN]  : Using BATT (Charge:59%)                                   45 secs   
2013-10-25 06:54:27 CEST Assertions             PID 18(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0xe0000135c [System: No Assertions]              
2013-10-25 06:54:27 CEST Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:59%)                                  18 secs   
2013-10-25 06:54:29 CEST SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from com.apple.apsd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                    1831 ms       
2013-10-25 06:54:29 CEST WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None                                                   
2013-10-25 06:54:45 CEST Assertions             PID 18(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0xe0000136f [System: No Assertions]
```

And so on throughout the entire night. The console says `2013-10-25 06:41:20,000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: ?` for every wake, so I guess my only shot is trying to figure out what `DarkWake [CDN]` means which there doesn't seem to be any info on. Also, this is while the Mac is on battery and with `pmset -g darkwakes 0` (I.e. Power Nap turned off for battery).

Comment: Have you attempted to [reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) or [zap the PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) to see if that helps? Do you have all external devices or other media (DVD/SD card) disconnected when testing (Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for device enumeration")? "InternalPreventSleep" may be an assertion that is preventing sleep?

Comment: Did both of those, no dice. Nope, no external devices connected.

Comment: Rick, do you happen to be running a virtual machine of any kind in the background? I'm seeing the same issue as you and wondering whether that could be a culprit...

Comment: Nope, I hade no VMs.

Comment: Is System Preferences / Energy Saver / Wake for network access checked? Maybe something pings your machine regularly or something similar is happening?

Comment: Yes it's on but that only applies to when the power adapter is plugged in. This also happens regardless of what Wi-Fi I'm on and even with Wi-Fi turned off.

Comment: Hey Rick, can you check if this still happens when you switch off Automatic Updates and Automatic App Downloads in System Preferences / App Store ? I have a sneaking suspicion it could theoretically be overdoing its software updates check since I'm seeing this behaviour on my Mac Mini server when I have caching server on, but none of this behaviour when it is off

Comment: Nope, still not working. Also tried disabling push notifications which didn't help. I did however have a look at the assertions it's printing during sleep and they are DeclUser and kDisp. According to [PMAssertions.h](https://github.com/aosm/PowerManagement/blob/master/pmconfigd/PMAssertions.c) they are, respectively, kDeclareUserActivity and kIOPMDriverAssertionPreventDisplaySleepBit. Specifically the second one seems interesting, perhaps it's somehow driver related?

Answer (score 4):

My workaround was to disable sleep using `sudo pmset -b standby 0`. Not really a fix but a temporary workaround until I revisit the issue.

Comment: I solved [similar issue](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219675/rmbp-early-2015-wakes-from-sleep-every-minute) with setting MBP to always hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue with my Macbook Air 2013 since upgrading to Mavericks

SMC and PRAM reset did not solve the problem.

After 3 hours sleeping on battery, Mac tries to change from sleep to DeepSleep (hibernate) mode.  Then, constantly waking itself back up each minute afterwards until the battery drains to <1%.

It has to be a bug on Apple side.

Comment: My workaround was to disable sleep using `sudo pmset -b standby 0`. I thought it might be related to Better Touch Tool since it's gotten a bunch of "Mavericks compatibility" updates but I haven't tried re-enabling hibernate since those, the battery life is still great even without that.

Comment: @Rick Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Sure, but it's not really an answer as much as a temporary workaround.