# rMBP Early 2015 wakes from sleep every minute

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake

My Macbook Pro 13" after upgrading to El Capitan 10.11.2 wakes from sleep every minute. This effectively drains battery overnight.

Tried to reset SMC, turned off wifi but nothing helps.

Does anybody else having similar problem?

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"
Dec 15 08:55:59 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:56:32 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:56:32 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:57:06 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:57:06 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:57:40 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:57:40 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:58:14 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:58:14 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:58:48 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:58:48 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:59:21 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:59:21 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 08:59:55 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 08:59:55 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:00:29 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:00:29 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:01:02 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:01:02 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:01:36 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:01:36 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:02:10 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:02:10 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:02:44 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:02:44 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:03:19 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:03:19 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:03:52 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:03:52 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:04:26 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:04:26 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:05:00 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:05:00 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:05:34 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:05:34 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:06:09 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:06:09 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
Dec 15 09:06:42 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: ARPT (Network)
Dec 15 09:06:42 ikrtinec kernel[0] <Notice>: [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

Comment: I have the same behavior.  Are you in an apartment / dense urban setting where your machine is in range of an AirPort in it doesn't know?

Answer (score 2):

Changed my hibernate mode from 3 to 25 via `pmset`. This forces Mac OS X to always hibernate to disk, and power off memory. Wakes are a bit slower but battery drain is gone.

Would like to have proper solution, though.

Command:

`sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25`

Excerpt from man page:

> hibernatemode = 25 is only settable via pmset. The system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage
>        (the disk), and will remove power to memory. The system will restore from disk image. If you want "hibernation" - slower sleeps, slower wakes, and better battery life, you should use this setting.